# accessing on child attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

inside view page I have several div which id's starts with `my-` prefix,

```
<div id="my-div1"><img src="/img/1.jpg" /></div>
<div id="my-div2"><img src="/img/2.jpg" /></div>
<div id="my-div3"><img src="/img/3.jpg" /></div>
```

in js code I'm iterating trough each element and I want to apply certain function child img element, in this case backstretch

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('div[id^="my-"]').each(function () {
         $(this).css("background-size", "100% 100%");
         $(this).css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");  
         // this doesn't work              
         $(this).children("img").backstretch($(this).attr('src'));
     })
});
```

when I test  `$(this).children("img").length`returns actual number of img under each div but I dont know how to pass it's src attribute value to backstretch function?

Comment: backstretch in jquery???

Comment: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [the documentation](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch), it doesn't look like `backstretch` supports passing in a function (the way may jQuery setter functions do), so you're stuck with [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each):

```
$(this).children("img").each(function() {
    $(this).backstretch(this.src);
});
```

Note that I'm not bothering to use jQuery for accessing the `src`, there's already a DOM property there ready and waiting. :-)

Or if you want to apply `backstretch` to the **div**, since each div only has one image, you can do this:

```
$(this).backstretch($(this).find("img").attr("src"));
```

`attr` will return the `src` of the first image in the div.

And finally, since `backstretch` supports multiple images as a slideshow, **if** your divs were going to have more than one image, you could use `children("img").map(...).get()` to get an array of their `src` 
attributes:

```
$(this).backstretch($(this).children("img").map(function() {
    return this.src;
}).get());
```

Comment: This should be considered as a perfect answer. I can only vote 1x.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('div[id^="my-"]').each(function () {
         $(this).children("img").each(function() {
             $(this).backstretch($(this).attr("src"));
         });
     })
});
```

Comment: You probably mean `$(this).attr("src")` ? Or like@T.J. Crowder just `this.src`